# How do I pass a list of variable names separated by "+" into a function

Tags: r, function, paste

I am using the lrm function in R for logistic regression that needs a list of variable names separated by "+":

```
lrm(rating~X1+X2+X3+X4+X5+X6+X7+X8+X9+X10,data=d5)
```

There are more than 10, and I don't want to write them all out. Is there a way I can use `paste()` to make the function work?

Here is how I made a string of Xis separated by +:

```
x = "X1"
for(i in 2:10){
  xi = paste("X",i,sep="")
  x = paste(x,xi,sep="+")
}
```

None of what I tried so far worked:

```
lrm(rating~x,data=d5)
lrm(rating~paste(x),data=d5)
lrm(rating~get(paste(x)),data=d5)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed you can:

```
paste0( "X" , 1:10 , collapse = "+" )
#[1] "X1+X2+X3+X4+X5+X6+X7+X8+X9+X10"
```

Or more specifically you probably want to pass the function a `formula` object which you can make with `as.formula` like this:

```
fmla <- as.formula( paste0( "rating ~ " , paste0( "X" , 1:10 , collapse = "+" ) ) )
# rating ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5 + X6 + X7 + X8 + X9 + X10

#  Then use it like any other variable
lrm( fmla , data=d5 )
```

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use `paste` in the data argument and then use `Y ~ .`

```
lrm( rating~., data=d5[ , c("rating", paste("X", 1:20, collapse="+"))] )
```

You need to use `collapse` rather than `sep` to get one rather than twenty elements in the returned value.